# Totally a mySQL trigger happiness issue

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, sql-insert, cascade

So I create my lil DB and then use the thing. I add two tables and now all I wanna do is this: when a user is inserted into the USERS table, also insert some default info into USER_ACCOUNT table that corresponds to the newly inserted user. Clearly I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what... Thanks in advance. =)

```
CREATE DATABASE REST_PROJECT;
USE REST_PROJECT;

CREATE TABLE USERS (
    UserID              INT Primary Key AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    UserEmail           VARCHAR(30),
    UserPassword        VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE USER_ACCOUNT (
    UserAccountID         INT Primary Key AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    OwnerUserID           INT,
    UserAccountName       VARCHAR(30),
    UserAccountType       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    UserAccountBalence    INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (OwnerUserID) REFERENCES USERS(UserID)
);

DELIMITER //
 CREATE TRIGGER makeDefaultUserAccount
 AFTER INSERT ON USERS
 For each row
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO USER_ACCOUNT 
    (UserAccountName, UserAccountType, UserAccountBalence) 
    values ('Default Account','default', 100);
END; //
```

Comment: So what actually happens when you run this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE DATABASE REST_PROJECT;
USE REST_PROJECT;

CREATE TABLE `USERS` (
    UserID              BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    UserEmail           VARCHAR(50),
    UserPassword        VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE `USER_ACCOUNT` (
    UserAccountID         BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    UserID                BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    UserAccountName       VARCHAR(30),
    UserAccountType       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    UserAccountBalance    DECIMAL(19,6),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_USER_ACCOUNT_UserID` FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`)
        REFERENCES `USERS`.`UserID` (`UserID`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `makeDefaultUserAccount`
AFTER INSERT ON `USERS`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO USER_ACCOUNT (OwnerUserID, UserAccountName, UserAccountType, UserAccountBalance) 
    VALUES (NEW.UserID, 'Default Account','default', 100);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Notes**

- Notice the changes in the `datatype` of the `primary keys`, yes, if you expect `large` scale data inside your system that would be the `initial setup` that will fit you
- Changes also in the `foreign key` part of you `USER_ACCOUNT` table, should comply with the related key of the `reference table's column`, and should also `cascade` for any changes
- Changed `UserAccountBalence` into `UserAccountBalance`, and also the `datatype` to accommodate the `currency value` that will be saved in the said column
- Regarding the `UserEmail` column in your `USERS` table, changed in into `50` from `30`, you need to give the application some breathing room incase `validation` suddenly failed
- Updated the trigger area to also save the `key` that you will use in your `foreign key`

Comment: I made a small change to the CREATE TABLE `USER_ACCOUNT`  statement:
Instead of REFERENCES `USERS`.`UserID` (`UserID`)
I used REFERENCES `USERS`(`UserID`)
And everything totally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the error message I'm only guessing, but I suspect the fact that you're not satisfying the FK constraint is to blame. Your trigger code should probably be

```
DELIMITER //
  CREATE TRIGGER makeDefaultUserAccount
    AFTER INSERT ON USERS
    For each row
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO USER_ACCOUNT 
          (OwnerUserID, UserAccountName, UserAccountType, UserAccountBalence) 
        values (NEW.UserID, 'Default Account','default', 100);
    END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

which sets `USER_ACCOUNT.OwnerUserID` to the value of `USERS.UserID` that was just inserted.